# block requests from domain

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out how best to block requests from a certain domain.
I have found that there is a site that is scrapping data using PhP.
I believe (based on my tests and looking at logs) that they are doing this with every request instead of using a cron job.
I don't know enough about PhP to know if I am going down the right path or not. But I have the URL of the PhP page (I will just block the entire domain).
My website is built on Rails.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to block the user when he hits your server. If you are running Apache, you can add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} badsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```